# Linking to profile page adding to URL based on current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Working on a Ruby on Rails project using ERB. I am trying to link a user to their profile page. For example, clicking on the dropdown link and then profile should bring you to site.com/users/1 if you are logged in as User 1.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="users/<%= current_user.id %>">Profile</a
```

This works on all the pages, however when I move to the profile page, it for some reason changes to site.com/users/users/1 if I click on the Profile link while on the profile thus giving me an error. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to follow the convention:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user), class: "dropdown-item" %>
```

Another option is:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="<%= user_path(current_user) %>">Profile</a>
```

But if you insist on your way, try adding a slash (/) before "users/<%= current_user.id %>" as follows:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/<%= current_user.id %>">Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rails way is to use `link_to`. It will automatically update the url based on your host.

So something like this must do the job:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %>

<%= link_to current_user.email, user_path(current_user) %>
```